# The Visual Studio for Mac compile error: Your project file doesn't list 'win' as a "RuntimeIdentifier"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-mac

This error started occuring when I modified the `.csproj` contents. But after that i restored the original version. The error still persists, actually with no sensible reason.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/NuGet/Microsoft.NuGet.targets(5,5): Error: Your project file doesn't list 'win' as a "RuntimeIdentifier". You should add 'win' to the "RuntimeIdentifiers" property in your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.
```

`.csproj` file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{D1B1F4F8-C9CF-4DC4-966D-DD7FF4683A1C}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>...</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>...</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <PackOnBuild>true</PackOnBuild>
    <PackageId>...</PackageId>
    <PackageVersion>0.1</PackageVersion>
    <Authors>Mondonno</Authors>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
    <Owners>...</Owners>
    <PackageProjectUrl>...</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>...</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <PackageTags>...</PackageTags>
    <Title>...</Title>
    <Description>...</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\AirlyNet.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup> 
  <ItemGroup>
     ...
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

I tried to add the `RuntimeIdentifier` and `RuntimeIdentifiers` but facing the same error. Rebuilding or refreshing project have not helped.

Comment: Can you provide more info on how you are getting this error? I created a C# library project, added the Newtonsoft.Json package to it, then copied the package info you added to the first PropertyGroup, but I cannot reproduce any build error. My only guess is that the project has a project.assets.json file in its obj directory (which is causing problems since the project has a packages.config file) which should be removed (you could try deleting the entire obj directory.

Comment: @MattWard So much thanks!!!! It now get compiled and all unit-tests passed, now i tried to create the nuget package but throwing to me the following error: 

Error MSB4057: The "Pack" target does not exist in the project (MSB4057)

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Pack is only supported on SDK style projects on macOS. Classic projects, such as the one you have created, do not support Pack out of the box. If you cannot convert it to an SDK style project the only current option you have would be to install the NuGet.Build.Packaging nuget package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Build.Packaging/

Comment: Not sure - repository url can be defined in the csproj file - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target

Comment: the first comment from @matt-ward worked for me as well after like a two hours of banging my head with walls
 Thanks Man and No Thanks to obj folder 

Comment: I don't use VS, but the same issues in Rider. To clean bin and obj helps usually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem i deleted `obj` directory from my solution folder 
Something was broken in it and when VS regenereted it problem was gone
Thanks to **@Matt Ward** who suggested this in question comments.